# "Full Calendar" in PrimeNG can't add time

Tags: ionic2, primeng

I am working on the PrimeNG to create the schedule : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

I see that I only add date to the schedule. I want to add the specific time to schedule.

Do you have any ideas about my issues ?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `p-dialog`, add the `[showTime]="true"` property to your `p-calendar` control